# What is order of the Wolff Cluster algorithm?

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, ising-model, algorithms

What is the order of the [Wolff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolff_algorithm) Cluster update algorithm for Ising Model 2D and 3D?

Comment: Isn't this something that ought to be described in any paper/book on the subject?

Comment: Not saying that because I know the answer, but I'd have assumed that it'd be discussed in those places (other algorithms I've used certainly have been).

Comment: no! I searched everywhere and find nothing, I think it is O(L^3)

Comment: and it strongly depends on temperature!